# Angular filter with typescript is not working after minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, minify, angularjs-filter

I wrote an angular filter with typescript which works fine until I minify the source code.

**Here is the filter:**

```
module App.Test {

    export interface IGroupingFilter extends ng.IFilterService {
        (name:"grouping-filter"): (collection:any[]) => collection:any[];
    }

    class GroupingFilter {
        static $inject:string[] = ["underscore"];

        static ConvertDateTime(item:any):number {
            var time = "" + item.time;
            var newTime = (time.length == 3) ? "0" + time : time;

            return +(item.pickupDate.replace(/\-/g, '') + newTime);
        }

        public static Factory(underscore:UnderscoreStatic) {
            return underscore.memoize((collection:any[]) => {
                var groupKey = "id";

                var group:any = underscore.groupBy(collection, (item:any) => {
                    return item[groupKey];
                });

                var grpArray = [];
                angular.forEach(group, (item) => {
                    grpArray.push({
                        "groupKey": item[0][groupKey],
                        "items": item
                    });
                });

                var grpArraySorted = underscore.sortBy(grpArray, (grpObj:any) => {
                    var min:any = underscore.min(grpObj.items, (item:any) => {
                        return GroupingFilter.ConvertDateTime(item);
                    });

                    return GroupingFilter.ConvertDateTime(min);
                });

                return grpArraySorted;
            });
        }
    }

    angular.module("app").filter("groupingFilter", GroupingFilter.Factory);
}
```

**Here is the minified version:**

```
var App;
!function (t) {
    var e;
    !function (t) {
        var e = function () {
            function t() {
            }

            return t.ConvertDateTime = function (t) {
                var e = "" + t.time, r = 3 == e.length ? "0" + e : e;
                return +(t.pickupDate.replace(/\-/g, "") + r)
            }, t.Factory = function (e) {
                return e.memoize(function (r) {
                    var n = "id", i = e.groupBy(r, function (t) {
                        return t[n]
                    }), o = [];
                    angular.forEach(i, function (t) {
                        o.push({groupKey: t[0][n], items: t})
                    });
                    var a = e.sortBy(o, function (r) {
                        var n = e.min(r.items, function (e) {
                            return t.ConvertDateTime(e)
                        });
                        return t.ConvertDateTime(n)
                    });
                    return a
                })
            }, t.$inject = ["underscore"], t
        }();
        angular.module("app").filter("groupingFilter", e.Factory)
    }(e = t.Test || (t.Test = {}))
}(App || (App = {}));
```

**Here is the angular error message**

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <-
>   groupingFilterFilter

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it does not work when minified is that you inject `"underscore"` into the `FooFilter` class not the actual filter, which is the result of `FooFilter.Factory`. To create such a simple filter you don't really need a class, just pass a simple function.

```
angular.module('app').filter('fooFilter', fooFilter);

fooFilter.$inject = ['underscore'];

function fooFilter(underscore) {
    return underscore.memoize((collection:any[]) => {
        return underscore.shuffle(collection);
    });
}
```

If you really want to write the filter factory function as a static class method, you could use the array syntax like this:

```
 angular.module("app")
   .filter("groupingFilter", ['underscore', GroupingFilter.Factory]);
```

Remove the `$inject` array from your class in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot @hansmaad! My actual filter is a little more complex. I use methodes as well. I would like to keep the class.

Comment: @stevo Can you edit your question and show how you want to use methods with your filter?

Comment: I edited the question with my actual filter. Thanks so much again!

Comment: @stevo There are only static functions in your example. There is no reason for a class. But I added a way to use that class in my answer.